# XMPP server does not respond to Smack login request

Tags: java, xmpp, smack

I'm trying to establish a connection to an XMPP server using smack.

```
ConnectionConfiguration cf = new ConnectionConfiguration("jabber.ccc.de");
cf.setTruststorePassword("changeme");
this.connection = new XMPPConnection(cf);
this.connection.connect();
this.connection.login("user", "password");
```

But whenever logging in I get an XMPPException (No response from the server.: ) and the socket gets closed.

Any ideas what's going wrong here?

Regards

Comment: I assume jabber.ccc.de uses the standard XMPP port?

Comment: I tried ConnectionConfiguration("jabber.ccc.de", 5222) and ConnectionConfiguration("jabber.ccc.de", 5223). Both with the same results. They are using ejabberd on that server.

Regards

Comment: Which call causes the exception? .connect() or .login()?

Comment: btw, I'd recommend using your own XMPP server for development. It's often easier to spot problems.

Comment: The problem occurs on login. I normally use an isolated XMPP server for real development, but right now I just want to try out smack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried seeing what the actual XMPP data being sent to/from the server is?

Try adding this to your code at startup:

```
System.setProperty("smack.debugEnabled", "true");
XMPPConnection.DEBUG_ENABLED = true;
```

Comment: Thanks, the server on the other side seems to act weird. I just set up my own Openfire server like sfussenegger suggested. I consider this Problem as solved now.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

This problem was addressed by a person called Davanum; see the [link](http://davanum.wordpress.com/2007/12/31/android-just-use-smack-api-for-xmpp/)

The problem is :
you are behind a slow internet connection. 
You need to increase time out for packet reply in smack config.

Strangely, you can get this problem, only the first time, after a boot of the client system (windows).

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
ConnectionConfiguration cf = new ConnectionConfiguration("jabber.ccc.de",5222, "test");
cf.setTruststorePassword("changeme");
this.connection = new XMPPConnection(cf);
this.connection.connect();
this.connection.login("user", "password");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put the following line before you make the connection.

```
SASLAuthentication.supportSASLMechanism("PLAIN");
```